# How to retrieve youtube thumbnails using Google API Client Library for Java

Tags: java, android, google-api-java-client

I would be obliged, if you could kindly let me know  the means by which I can retrieve the youtube thumbnails using Google API Client Library for Java, similar to the way in which we fetched thumbnails using gdata.

```
List<String> thumbnails = new LinkedList<String>();
for (MediaThumbnail mediaThumbnail : mediaGroup.getThumbnails()) {
    thumbnails.add(mediaThumbnail.getUrl());
}
```

Looking forward,
Regards,
Rony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the example URL from the [reference page](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_media:thumbnail):

> URL: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=football+-soccer&orderby=published&start-index=11&max-results=10&v=2&alt=jsonc

we can extract an example of one of the relevant pieces of JSON:

```
"thumbnail": {
    "sqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/PpUgUrU5XUA/default.jpg",
    "hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/PpUgUrU5XUA/hqdefault.jpg"
}
```

You can modify the [sample classes](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/youtube-jsonc-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/youtube/?repo=samples#youtube/model) to parse the thumbnail object.

Comment: Hi,Many thanks for your reply. Not sure, whether I am posting trivial questions. Kindly refer YouTubeManager source code in http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/getting-started-with-youtube-java-api.html . I am searching for a similar method wherein I can retrieve the thumbnails pertaining to the general search, say, if I search most viewed videos using http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed , I get thumbnails corresponding to each video from that method. I am not finding any alternative classes for mediaContent, mediagroup etc. to obtain the result that i need.